# Rspec spec/ generates errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails through Michael Hartl's tutorials  and am getting the following errors when I run "rspec spec/". What might be causing this? Is something missing in my routes.rb file?

```
    $ rspec spec/
C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or meth
od `gitFirstApp' for main:Object (NameError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths
'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from c:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>
'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
iles'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/cor
```

`pages_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end

end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
gitFirstApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"

  get "pages/contact"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `gitFirstApp` does not exist. That name is a module so it should start with a capital (eg `GitFirstApp`). Check the name of the first module you see in `config/application.rb` and that will show you the module you should be using.

Comment: The (only) module in config/application.rb is FirstApp. When I change the name in the routes.rb file from gitFirstApp to GitFirstApp I get this:

'$ rake routes rake aborted! uninitialized constant GitFirstApp C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/config/routes.rb:1:in <top (required)>\' c:in execute_if_updated\' C:/Users/Robert B. Miller/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in \`<top (required)>\' Tasks: TOP => routes => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace)'

Comment: Given the instructions in this answer, you should have used `FirstApp`, not `GitFirstApp`. Also, if you're following the Hartl tutorial, where did `gitFirsApp` come from? I don't believe that name is referred to anywhere in the tutorial.

Comment: Got it! I must have had my cursor in the wrong place when I started typing a git command. The "git" in gitFirstApp doesn't belong there at all. My bad. Thanks!